Why in QM the solution to Laguerre equations are ONLY Laguerre polynomials?
I am studying eigenfunction methods to solve Fokker-Planck equations and I got stuck with a calculation that is related to some typical problems in QM. In particular, the radial part of an hydrogen atom can be characterized through a Laguerre equation of the type ,
$$x y''+(1-x)y+\lambda y =0.$$
In undergraduate notes, I've always seen statements like "the solution to Laguerre equations are Laguerre polynomials". However, this is a second order ODE which has two linearly independent solutions, as stated in mathworld.wolfram,
$$ y(x) = c_1 L_\lambda (x) + c_2 U(-\lambda,1,x).$$
Where $L$ stands for the Laguerre polynomial and $U$ is the second standard solution to Kummer's equation . What is the reasoning in QM to discard the confluent hypergeometric function $U$? I.e. Why should $c_2=0$?

You crossposted this from M.SE with a lot of context stripped out. I just gave an answer there that takes from DLMF and shows that the $U(-\lambda,1,x)$ never works.

This is related to the fact that the solutions in the textbook are written only for the discrete spectrum of energies. We are interested in the normalized solutions, i.e. such that
\begin{equation*}
\int d^3x |\Psi|^2
\end{equation*}
were finite. However, if you take arbitrary energies one of the solutions will have singularity at $r=0$ and another one will grow with $r\rightarrow+\infty$. This will break down the normalizability.
For the discrete spectrum of energies you will find the solutions that have good behavior both at $r=0$ and $r\rightarrow+\infty$. This solutions will be normalizable. But the second solution will in contrast have bad behavior both at $r=0$ and for $r\rightarrow+\infty$.

Thanks! I am curious, if you were interested in the continuous part of the spectrum, would there be another physical constraint similar to the normalization that you mention affecting the possible values of $c_1$ and $c_2$?

@Javi It's more trickier with the continuous spectrum. They are not actual physical wave functions but they maybe combined into a normalized wavepacket. You need a set of such functions (in addition to the actual eigenfunctions forming a discrete spectrum) that would be complete i.e. any normalizable wavefunction should be their superposition with normalizable amplitude function. You also don't want wavepackets with normalizable amplitude function to be non-normalizable.

@Javi For the standard QM situations it is enough to require them to be non-singular and at worst oscillators at infinity. There are theorems that put this on a solid ground. However even in 1d QM you may consider potentials with such singularities or such unboundeness from below that more tricky stuff happens.
